# How to get Uri from actual path in React Native?

Tags: path, react-native, storage, uri

I want to get this Uri :
"content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata%2Fcom.roxiit.admin%2Ffiles%2FReactNativeRecordScreen%2FHD2021-08-16-10-37-27.mp4"

From this path :
"storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.roxiit.admin/files/ReactNativeRecordScreen/HD2021-08-16-10-37-27.mp4"

Is there any way to apply this ?